# Failed-Server problem error while downloading reports in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to save the output of my Shiny app as PDF and word file. Like it happens [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html).

The same code can be found on Shiny server and reports get generated perfectly but when I run it on local the output generated is a blank HTML file whereas the PDF gives server error.
I have already tried, creating a blank

> report.Rmd

```
fluidPage(
  title = 'Download a PDF report',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                  choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('regPlot')
    )
  )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# list of data sets
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "cars" = mtcars,
           "longley" = longley,
           "MLB" = mlb11,    
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure, 
           "Your Data" = df())
  })

# dependent variable
  output$dv = renderUI({
    selectInput('dv', h5('Dependent Variable'), choices = names(datasetInput()))
  })

# independent variable
  output$iv = renderUI({
    selectInput('iv', h5('Independent Variable'), choices = names(datasetInput()))
  })

# regression formula
  regFormula <- reactive({
    as.formula(paste(input$dv, '~', input$iv))
  })

# bivariate model
  model <- reactive({
     lm(regFormula(), data = datasetInput())
  })


# create graphics 

# data view 
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })

# summary statistics
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
      summary(cbind(datasetInput()[input$dv], datasetInput()[input$iv]))
  })

# histograms   
  output$distPlot_dv <- renderPlot({
    x    <- datasetInput()[,input$dv]  
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins_dv + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white', main = 'Dependent Variable', xlab = input$dv)
  })


  output$distPlot_iv <- renderPlot({
    x    <- datasetInput()[,input$iv]  
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins_iv + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white', main = 'Independent Variable', xlab = input$iv)
  })

# scatter plot 
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
     plot(datasetInput()[,input$iv], datasetInput()[,input$dv],
       xlab = input$iv, ylab = input$dv,  main = "Scatter Plot of Independent and Dependent Variables", pch = 16, 
       col = "black", cex = 1) 

     abline(lm(datasetInput()[,input$dv]~datasetInput()[,input$iv]), col="grey", lwd = 2) 
  })

# correlation matrix
  output$corr <- renderGvis({
    d <- datasetInput()[,sapply(datasetInput(),is.integer)|sapply(datasetInput(),is.numeric)] 
    cor <- as.data.frame(round(cor(d), 2))
    cor <- cbind(Variables = rownames(cor), cor)
    gvisTable(cor) 
  })

# bivariate model
  output$model <- renderPrint({
    summary(model())
  })

# residuals
  output$residuals_hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(model()$residuals, main = paste(input$dv, '~', input$iv), xlab = 'Residuals') 
  })

  output$residuals_scatter <- renderPlot({
    plot(model()$residuals ~ datasetInput()[,input$iv], xlab = input$iv, ylab = 'Residuals')
    abline(h = 0, lty = 3) 
  })

  output$residuals_qqline <- renderPlot({
    qqnorm(model()$residuals)
    qqline(model()$residuals) 
  })

# hotable
  output$hotable1 <- renderHotable({
    df <- data.frame(String = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 
                     Numeric1 = numeric(10), 
                     Numeric2 = numeric(10))
    return(df)
  }, readOnly = FALSE)

df <- reactive({
  hot.to.df(input$hotable1) # this will convert your input into a data.frame
  })


# download report
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
    paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
    input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
    ))
  },

  content = function(file) {
    src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
    owd <- setwd(tempdir())
    on.exit(setwd(owd))
    file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd')

    library(rmarkdown)
    out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
      input$format,
      PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
    ))
    file.rename(out, file)
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "report.html"
```

Did you try changing this to .pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the document to render based on the code provided above (I have also tested word output). I had to make a few changes based on the code provided in your link.

You need to ensure / take note of the following:

1. The `render()` function in the `rmarkdown` package must take in a raw `xx.Rmd` template as an input which needs to be stored in your working directory.
2. The `render()` function then passes the raw input as described in (1) to `knitr` which executes all of the `R` code chunks and creates a new `.Rmd` document which is subsequently passed into `pandoc` which generates your final output (pdf, html, word)
3. If you want a pdf document, you need `pdflatex` installed on your machine and this can be obtained via the Miktex distribution (https://miktex.org/download) or the TeX Live distribution (https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html).
4. Before the document can be knitted, you need to tell it which `pandoc` method to use and this needs to be in the form of `rmarkdown::html_document(), rmarkdown::pdf_document(), rmarkdown::word_document()`.
5. Thus the render function pertaining to your example will be `rmarkdown::render(report.Rmd, pdf_document())` or `rmarkdown::render(report.Rmd, pdf_document())`

### R Markdown Example Template

Here is the `report.Rmd` template I have created as an example, please store this in your working directory:

````
---
title: "Test R Markdown"
author: "RickTastic!!"
date: "January 9, 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. You need a document like this to pass to the render function. You will then want to embed your output code like this `r sum(c(1, 2, 3))`

## Showing the slider number

```{r sliderNumber, include = FALSE}
sliderNumber <- function() return(as.numeric(input$slider))
```

The input selected from the slider is `r sliderNumber()`. Your function needs to be defined in your .Rmd template.
````

### R Source Code which uses the above template and returns the slider number selected when the download button is clicked

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50), downloadButton("report", "Generate report"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sliderInput <- reactive(return(as.numeric(input$slider)))

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() return("myReport.html"),
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath("report.Rmd")
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, "report.Rmd", overwrite = TRUE)
      out <- render("report.Rmd", html_document())
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: hi @RickTastic I appreciate your help but the above code downloads the file in HTML, but I want  to generate the same report in PDF and if possible a presentation. So I have changed the above code to produce a reproducible example where you can have buttons to generate report in .html or .pdf or .docs  What will be the .Rmd file required for the same ?

Comment: Yes Sir @Direxions_Manav. Consider the `.Rmd ` file as the raw input into the render function. You still need to knit the document into pdf file. The input "language" is still the same (.Rmd). You can remove the `output:html_output` from the `.Rmd` template. All you need to do is to knit your content into `pdf` format by using `rmarkdown::pdf_document()` instead of `rmarkdown::html_document()`. But please note that you will need `pdflatex` installed. Please up vote if you no longer get the Failed Server Problem error :-).

Comment: i have pdflatex  installed, and with the above code am able to generate html reports but not pdf reports even after using pdf_document()

Comment: @Direxions_Manav Okay, your code is fine since you can knit into `html` and `word`. We also know that the template has no issues since we can knit into `html` and `word`. What I suggest is the following testing strategy: 1. Open `cmd` and type in `pdflatex`. If you get an output, all is well and you can continue to the next steps. If not, then you need to fix the `pdflatex` issue first. 2. Create an offline (non shiny) rendering script to see if you can knit the `.Rmd` into `pdf`. The console will provide you with some error message as to why it cannot knit.

Comment: Hi @RickTastic, I checked and I do have pdflatex installed. have you seen the changed code in my above code. My original question is for this code. So can you please provide a .Rmd code to run the same ? which exports the result in pdf format.

Comment: I can't accept this as the right answer as this doesn't completely answer my question.

Comment: Hi @Direxions_Manav .Rmd is just a template, you will have to tailor it to your specific needs. I have tested on my end an the proof of concept works. I suspect the reason why it is not exporting to pdf on your end could be due to missing packages in `pdflatex`. The R console will throw you a log to see why it is not exporting to pdf. But I will  investigate further.

Comment: any sample .Rmd code for the above app would be really of great help, just as a sample that it works, i will thereafter entire code and put result here for everyone's use